# Why MUI Autocomplete options type can't be A[] | B[]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

So, I tried to create an autocomplete that can accept both options that are of type `string[]` and options of type `{title: string, year: number}[]`. Something like this:

```
const top5Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 }
];

export default function FreeSolo() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} direction={"row"} sx={{ width: 600 }}>
      <UnionAutocomplete options={top5Films} />  // {title: string, year: number}[]
      <UnionAutocomplete options={top5Films.map(({ title }) => title)} />  // string[]
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

I wrote a component that does what I intended, however although the example is working, I get the following type error.

```
export function UnionAutocomplete(props: {
  options: string[] | { title: string; year: number }[];
}) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      fullWidth
      // error on options
      //Type '{ title: string; year: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string'
      options={props.options} 
      getOptionLabel={
        // title here is never cause option considered only as a string
        (option) => (typeof option === "string" ? option : option.title)
      }
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
  );
}
```

So my question is: why exactly can't I pass an array of either type `string[]` or type `{title: string, year: number}[]` to Autocomplete options. I find it difficult to understand what is stopping me from doing this.

I understand that I can just make two different components for different option types, but is there any more concise solution? Perhaps I somehow incorrectly specified the type itself.

The working code (despite the type errors) I wrote above can be found in this CodeSandbox.

[image: Edit awesome-platform-40mf0g]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types for `Autocomplete` are structured in a manner where it tries to resolve the type of a single option ([represented as `T` in the types](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-base/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.d.ts#L37)) and then expects the `options` prop to receive an [array of those](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-base/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.d.ts#L277).

The way you defined the type of your options is not compatible with that since you have two different "option" types. But with a small tweak, you can make it work. What you want is:

```
  options: (string | { title: string; year: number })[];
```

This allows MUI's types to determine that your individual options have a single type of `(string | { title: string; year: number })` and then the `options` prop is an array of those.

Here's a modified version of your sandbox demonstrating this approach:

https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-option-types-7ipfq4?file=/demo.tsx

If (as indicated in comments) you want to constrain this further to prevent an array that mixes the two types, you can use the following:

```
interface TitleYear {
  title: string;
  year: number;
}

export function UnionAutocomplete<
  ArrayType extends string[] | TitleYear[],
  OptionType extends string | TitleYear
>(props: { options: ArrayType }) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      fullWidth
      options={props.options as OptionType[]}
      getOptionLabel={
        (option) => (typeof option === "string" ? option : option.title) // why never ?
      }
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit autocomplete option types]

In the above example, `OptionType[]` is equivalent to my previous solution, but `ArrayType` is equivalent to what you had in your question. The net effect is that the input to `UnionAutocomplete` is constrained as desired and then the internal cast to `OptionType[]` allows MUI's types to resolve successfully.

Comment: Indeed, errors in Autocomplete really disappear. But the fact is that I was trying to separate the types so that when I want to pass data further, the array must contain either data of one type or another, but such a declaration says that I supposedly pass an array that can contain both `strings` AND `objects`. Can I infer from your answer that if I really want to separate options types, the best thing to do would be to make two separate components?

Comment: @ОлексійХолостенко I've added another approach to address this.